# How to capture request/response latency and DB query metrics in Play?

Tags: playframework, metrics, latency

For an API built using Play framework [1.2.3], how to collect request/response latency and db query metrics?
I am aware that enabling TRACE level logging prints the queries and the time taken for the results on the log files.
I am wondering if there is a programmatic way of retrieving the same for monitoring purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is module for that called jpastats:
[Module Page of jpastats](http://www.playframework.org/modules/jpastats)

This should collect the needed data for you.